# React-Native java HTTP GET request

Tags: java, android, express, request

I need to make HTTP Get request from my express js app, whenever I click notification action button.. This far, i've made a service that starts when i press the button, but i can't manage to make an HTTP get request.. Am I doing something wrong in this?

request function in service.

```
  public void http()  {
      try {
           URL url = new URL("http://192.168.199.58:8080/res");
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           urlConnection.disconnect();
           // tv.setText("Hello!");
           Log.i("NotificationService", "HTTP START ");

       }
       catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
           Log.e("httptest",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {
           Log.e("httptest",Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
       }
  }
```

And express js server

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/res', (req, res) => console.log("requested"))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Thanks for help :)